# Finding Free large-scale Databases to work with SQL Server Express or Developer

Tags: sql-server, large-data-volumes

I would like to improve my overall programming proficiency with SQL Server Express/Developer. My programming has so far  been effective only with "baby" databases with tables with fewer than 200 rows. Anyone know of free sources for databases with tables containing 100,000+ rows?
Thanks.

Comment: Generally this is considered a 'shopping list' question but might I suggest the stackoverflow database. Use your google-fu to find it

Comment: If you just want to improve your SQL, this is probably even easier: https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Thanks,  but I want to improve it while working in more " realistic" data settings . Most business-like settings will contain databases with 1000's of rows. You know if these sites offer APIs, and/or allow scraping?

Comment: I'm working with a database with 95 million rows. I believe the stackoverflow database is in that order of magnitude.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid:  Big-enough, thanks  :) can I scrape it? Does it provide APIs?

Comment: Here's a page with more info. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/ . This is for the download file, not the data.stackexchange access. You won't be able to restore this into Express, it will have to be Developer edition

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Excellent, thanks.